Is there any language which distinguishes between “un” as in “not” and “un” as in “inverse”?
I think in English there are examples of “un” meaning “doing an opposite resultative action to restore the original state of a thing” versus “un” simply meaning “not”.
You can “undo” something, or “unfriend” someone, assuming you were previously friends.
But on my Mail applications, messages that have not yet been sent are labeled “Unsent”, so that means “not sent”, not “sent and then modified to no longer have been sent”.
What is the name of these two semantic “aspects” or “moods” and does any language strictly distinguish them?

Probably most languages express these things distinctly, but more importantly, as you can read here, those un- are 2 etymologically different prefixes, not 1 prefix with multiple functions. un- for negation comes from Middle English un- ← Old English un- ← Proto-West Germanic *un- ← Proto-Germanic *un- ← Proto-Indo-European *n̥-, while un- for inversion comes from Middle English on- ← Old English on- ~ ond- ~ and- ← Proto-West Germanic *anda- ← Proto-Germanic *anda- ~ *andi- ← Proto-Indo-European *h₂énti.

And English also has other prefixes that are more specific. "non-" only means "not".

Esperanto has prefixes mal- (inverse) and ne- (not).

Latin has in- "not", but uses other prefixes when creating verbs of reversal (e.g. dē-, dis-, & re-, probably amongst others). Note that these other prefixes have other senses as well.
In most cases, those prefixes that create verbs of reversal only attach to verbs, whereas in- generally attaches to adjectives (or to nouns, in combination with a shift to the third declension in -is with the sense of "lacking, without, -less").
Likewise Old English had un- "un-" which applied to adjectives to indicate negation, and variously on-, ond-, and- "un-" which applied to verbs to indicate reversal. It's only in the Early Modern Period that these two sets of prefixes merge.
The ambiguity arises with participles of verbs. If you see a participle preceded by un- it's not clear whether the prefix was applied to the verb (and we then formed the participle), or if we formed the participle (and then applied the prefix to it). In the former case we would understand undone as "reversed", whereas in the latter we would understand it as "not done".
This ambiguity only exists however because the derivational morphology for these negated forms and for participles affect opposite edges of the word. If the negated forms were formed with a suffix (e.g. -n't, as was briefly popular online), we'd be able to distinguish between sentn't "not sent" & sendn'ted "sent, but then modified to no longer be sent".
It can also be avoided if the deverbal and deadjectival prefixes are not the same. E.g. in Latin we could distinguish between ingelātus "not frozen" and regelātus "thawed".
I'm not sure of any specific names for these two types of formations. I would describe the adjectives formed this way as negated forms (at least in the Indo-European languages mentioned here), and the verbs as verbs of reversal, but that's purely ad hoc. In principle I don't see any reason reversal couldn't be incorporated into a language's TAM system (most likely under mood, possibly aspect, if those elements are meaningfully distinct in that language).
In these particular languages (Latin, Old English, and Modern English) though, reversal cannot be part of the TAM system. Verbs of reversal form all the usual tenses, aspects, & moods, so it cannot be a tense, aspect or mood. That leaves the possibility that it is some other axis of the TAM system, but the fact that the morphemes forming them seem to be derivational rather than inflectional rules that out too (although admittedly, the derivational/inflectional distinction is not always completely clear).
They're just a particular semantic class of verbs.

Interesting, the Old English prefix and- that you mention is related the German ent-, which another answer gives as an example.

@CarstenS English is a Germanic language. We should expect that it looks more like its relatives when we look at earlier stages of it

Of course. I still find it interesting.

Old English also had prefix ne-, etymologically the same as in Balto-Slavic languages and Latin :) .

@Arfrever true, and ne- has the simple negation sense even with verbs

in- has its own potentially dangerous ambiguities, as seen in "inflammable"

@Henry Latin actually has 3 distinct in- prefixes: (1) in- for negation, ultimately from PIE negative particle *ne; (2) in- for various meanings, including "in", "within", "inside", intensifier etc., from preposition in, ultimately from PIE *h₁én; (3) in- for "after", ultimately from PIE *énu. So it is the same situation with phonetic convergence of unrelated words/affixes, as what happened with English un-. See also īnflammō.

@Henry yes, there is a phonetic convergence of unrelated prefixes there, but those ambiguities are separate from those of English un- and are not relevant to the case in question, as none of the in- prefixes (see Arfrever's comment) form verbs of reversal. Similarly Old English un- can also mean "bad, evil, wicked", but that isn't relevant to the question at hand

Slavic languages have distinct prefixes for these concepts:

Negation:

ne- (← Proto-Slavic *ne)
E.g. Czech ne- [ˈnɛ], Polish nie- [ɲɛ], Ukrainian не- [nɛ], Russian не- [ˈnʲe] ~ [nʲɪ]



Inversion of action:

ot- ~ od- (← Proto-Slavic *otъ)
E.g. Czech od- [ˈod] ~ [ˈot], Polish od- [ɔd] ~ [ɔt], Ukrainian від- [ʋʲid], од- [ɔd], Russian от- [ˈot] ~ [ˈod] ~ [ɐt] ~ [ɐd]

roz- ~ raz- (← Proto-Slavic *orz-)
E.g. Czech roz- [ˈroz] ~ [ˈros], Polish roz- [rɔz] ~ [rɔs], Ukrainian роз- [rɔz], Russian роз- [ˈroz] ~ рос- [ˈros] ~ раз- [rəz] ~ рас- [rəs]

vy- (← Proto-Slavic *vy-)
E.g. Czech vy- [ˈvɪ], Polish wy- [vɘ̟], Ukrainian ви- [ʋɪ], Russian вы- [vɨ]

iz- ~ z- (← Proto-Slavic *jьz-)
E.g. Czech z- [ˈz] ~ [ˈs], Polish z- [z] ~ s- [s] ~ ś- [ɕ], Ukrainian з- [z] ~ с- [s], Russian из- [ˈiz] ~ [ɪz] ~ ис- [ˈis] ~ [ɪs]


These prefixes also have other meanings.



Well, to a certain extent English does contrast simple negation and reversal. For example the prefix de-  indicates reversal not simple negation:

destabilise
deregulate

A different point  is that, to some extent, we might want to say that there are actually two un- prefixes in English, which are often readily distinguishable in terms of which words they appear on, rather than one polysemous one. There are several reasons:

As well as having two different meanings, the two prefixes have different etymologies. Here are the entries from Wiktionary:


Simple negation "From Middle English un-, from Old English un-, from Proto-West Germanic *un-, from Proto-Germanic *un-, from Proto-Indo-European *n̥-."
Reversal "From Middle English on-, from Old English on-, ond-, and- (“against, facing, toward; in return, back, without”), from Proto-West Germanic *anda-, from Proto-Germanic *anda-, *andi- (“against”), from Proto-Indo-European *h₂énti (“across, forth, forward, ahead”), from *h₂énts (“end, limit, forehead”)"


The reversal prefix is essentially verbal (but thus also appears on deverbal adjectives), whereas the negation suffix is mainly restricted to adjectives.
There are very restrictive semantic constraints on the use of the reversal prefix, as shown below.

Here is an excerpt from one of Geoff Pullum's talks for the Australian Broadcasting Corporation's Lingua Franca slot: "Why you can't Unhear this Talk". [You can listen to the whole talk at the linked-in page,  or read it if you click on the "transcript" button. Thanks to @user424874 for a working link to the audio].

Why you can't Unhear this Talk
Geoff Pullum: [...]
Suppose I told you that "flimmick" was a new verb that meant "to remove microchips from a computer for the purpose of recycling them in other equipment". Now, can you "unflimmick" a computer, by putting microchips back into it? Of course not. It would be as linguistically odd as unshearing a sheep.
But suppose, as an alternative, that I told you instead that flimmick was a rare and old fashioned word meaning "to tie something to the tail of an animal for the purpose of frightening it and annoying it". Now, can I tell a couple of cruel little boys, "For goodness' sake, unflimmick that poor puppy and stop being such little beasts." Yes, I can. That one sounds all right.
What is the generalisation, then? Here's the answer. There is a class of operations involving encumberment or concealment through surface attachment, and only the verbs that refer to operations of that sort take the reversing un prefix.
Binding, tying, or chaining involve attaching basically one-dimensional stuff to the surface of an object so that it is encumbered and partially covered.
Tangling is doing that to a one-dimensional object using parts of itself.
Covering, veiling, wrapping, and dressing involve putting basically two-dimensional stuff over the surface of a three-dimensional object so that it is hidden and to some degree encumbered.
Folding is doing that to a two-dimensional object using parts of itself.
Burdening, loading, and stacking involve putting objects on each other's upper surfaces so that the upper ones cover and encumber the lower ones.
Clogging is encumbering something such as a gutter or drain by attaching or loading things into it to stop water running down it.
So the verbs we get from reversing un are: unbind, untie, unchain, untangle; uncover, unveil, undress, unfold; unburden, unload, unstack, unclog, and that's about it.
Interestingly, we find undo, but only when the rather vague action verb do stands for something of the encumbering, covering, or attaching sort: you can undo your shoelaces, but you can't undo your homework; you can undo a parcel, but you can't undo a good deed.
It looks as though people who speak English actually have in the back of their minds a rough definition of this little class of covering, encumbering, and surface-attaching operations, and can tell intuitively which verbs belong. Whorf's names for covert classes of words of this sort -- hidden groupings that you can't spot by looking at the inflections or the syntax -- was cryptotypes. Hidden types of word, buried in an unconscious classification system inside your mind.
And the songwriter who produced the line "Un-break my heart" intuitively knew about the reversing un cryptotype, and built not one but three counterexamples into the song as a linguistic special effect.
So be careful how you treat your loved ones, because you can't "unbreak" a heart, or "uncry" someone's tears. You can unchain someone's heart, metaphorically, and send them away, but you can't bring spurned lovers back by unjilting them. You always hurt the one you love, but once you've done it, you can't unhurt them. The English language doesn't even permit you to literally talk about such things. So don't break anyone's heart, okay?


Reference
Lingua Franca: Why you can't Unhear this Talk. 2000. ABC Radio. September 11. 06.45 am

whilst it's certainly a good rule of thumb, Pullum's proposed rule would seem to deny the possibility of unsend and unfriend, both of which are definitely permitted.

@Tristan Both 'unfriend' and 'unsend' are about removing a mark/label attached to something or covering something. Those removing marks/labels meanings could be considered extensions of the uncovering meanings discussed by GKP. They seem to be inherently "unnable". They include the following verbs: untick, uncheck, unfriend, unlike, uncross, unflag

Even if a verb is used rarely, or in wishes or with "cannot" (see some quotations for uneat and undrink), or in fantasy books or games (maybe unkill), then it is still a verb.

@Arfrever Yes, but that does not include idiot websites (I'm not meaning just Wiktionary here) who try to backform the existence of verbs from adjectives when the verbs have never existed. There are zero instances of uneat in either COCa or BNC (of course lot's for the adjectives uneaten). And whilst I agree that one can verb anything on an adhoc basis, that doesn't mean that the adhocked verb  is a conventionalised verb in the language. There are no dictionaries that list Arfrever as a verb, even though you just Arfrevered the existence of 3 non-existent words!

OK, the talk is from 1999, so the most common usage of undo, namely in Word Processors or Spreadsheets or Image Processing, namely to revert the previous action, wasn't as pervasive as today. I find the omission remarkable nevertheless.

@SirCornflakes ?? Pullum has a whole  'paragraph' - an interesting one discussing undo, though (Paragraph in quotes because the original was the spoken text, not the written one). It's the 4th para from the end.

@Araucaria-him Yes, he has, about shoelaces and parcels that one can undo. I have read this. The undo in a Word Processor is quiie different from that, I think, and comes dangerously close to unhearing a talk.

@SirCornflakes Interesting. My intuition (see comment above to Tristan) is that many computerish electronic verbs relate metaphorically to the covering and uncovering of paper, now extended  to text-spaces on screen: 'uncheck, uncross, unfriend, unflag' and your 'undo' all involve removing marks covering text-space. Still, essentially, uncovering.

@Araucaria-him try this link for the audio talk https://www.abc.net.au/listen/programs/linguafranca/rn-summer-series2c-part-53a/4437968

@user424874 Brilliant! Thanks very much

In many content management systems, it is possible to "unpublish" an article. This involves concealment, but not through surface attachment; and it is the unpublishing, not the publishing, which involves concealment.

Other examples: When user unsets a variable in shell, it is actually deleted and not just concealed, and unsetting restores situation before first setting this variable. When user uncompresses / unpacks / unzips etc. an archive, he gains access to original data, which were previously compressed. When user unlinks a file, then immediately afterwards it is likely that data still remain (e.g. are not overwritten with zero bytes), but their location is marked as free and available for re-using, and content of new files can be stored in that location.

@Arfrever That's borrowing verbs that are already established un-verbs in the language. Verbs like unzip, unpack, unlink etc are just established un-verbs from the real world. They're un-verbs in the real world for the reasons given by GKP. Uncompress is novel, but the metaphor obviously complies with GKP's meanings. There may be the odd new coinage somewhere, but I don't really think that's particularly worrying. It's certainly not a freely occurring affix, unlike, say, the adjectival prefix anti-

High German is an example language: it has the prefix un- for negation, as in ungesendet "not sent" (as in the email example); but it uses other expressions for reversion, e.g., rückgängig machen "undo" or entfreunden "unfriend" (a very modern expression, mainly used in the context of social networks, showing the productivity of the prefix ent- for this kind of meaning modification).

rückgängig machen => ungeschehen machen. Still uses the -un.

@infinitezero Well, geschehen is yet another verb (here as the past participle)  newly introduced by your paraphrase, and it is this past participle  you are going to negate. There is no such thing as *unmachen in German.

@infinitezero ungeschehen by itself is not an inversion of action, it is just a negation. Of course you can add machen to anything to turn a negation into an inversion, e.g. unvollständig (negation) vs unvollständig machen (inversion). That does not change the fact that un- by itself always means negation, and ent- often means inversion.

Actually English is also differentiating those meanings by the word form:

undo, unfriend are verbs; the same way unsend can be interpreted too. (Although my spell checker recognize it, it's used in the web as a synonym of recalling a message - it's even used in Gmail's guidance)
on the other hand unsent is an adjective - similarly to undone which has a meaning - among others - that something is not done

It might be more visible in Hungarian when adjectives are created from verbs by changing the end of the word, not the beginning:

undo: visszacsinál
unsent: elküldetlen


Unsent & undone can mean both not-sent & not-done, but also sent-and-then-recalled & done-and-then-reversed. Participles are ambiguous here, because they can take either the adjectival or verbal un-
